# How to supress printing of warning massage in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script, which when it's finished running, it going to write some files into a directory. 
It prints a lot of warnings, which slows down the process, I'm looking for an effective way to prevent printing the warnings in the shell.
I added  `2> /dev/null` to end of my command at mybash.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
command -f file   2> /dev/null
```

the original command:

```
java -mx28000M -jar ChromHMM.jar BinarizeBam CHROMSIZES/hg19.txt /Volumes/Control/ /primary_bam_files/FCX/Control/Marks_Run1.txt /Volumes/Control/output1/
```

When I run my mybash.sh, it will write 20 different output files in a directory. 
However, when I use 2>/dev/null, it does not print any warning in the shell which is great but also does not write anything in the output directory which in principle should those 20 files. 
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Try assigning the output of the command to a variable
`var=$(command -f file )`

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. With this, does it will write warnings and the main output of the bashscript in a single file?

Comment: Redirecting errors to `/dev/null` shouldn't prevent it from writing to the output directory.

Comment: @h4x04 That won't redirect errors, only standard output.

Comment: what's your solution?

Comment: What you're doing should work, I can't think of a good reason why it doesn't.

Comment: do you mean var=$(command -f file ) this? 
my orginal approach doesn't work

Comment: @user2806363 That variable assignment just puts the standard output of `command -f file` into the variable, standard error still goes to the terminal, so it's not a solution to your problem. You don't want to stop normal output, just error messages.

Comment: It's like using `>/dev/null` rather than `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Can you post the actual script so we can see how the above command is related to the part of the script that writes to the output directory?

Comment: I just posted the original command

Comment: do never supress massages.

Comment: Consider redirecting stderr to a file , not /dev/nul (e.g 2>$HOME/errors ).  If you still don't get the 20 files you were expecting, review the error file and look for clues.

Comment: I did it, it writes errors and actual output in one file

Comment: What do you mean? Does it write the 20 expected output files one after another into a file named `errors`?

Comment: Yes, that's right, It writes all into one file unfortunatly

Comment: Does the script have permission to write on the paths where the 20 files are to be written? You may have already checked this but are the 20 files created/updated when you do not redirect the stderr to `\dev\null`?

Comment: I cheked it, and didn't work

Comment: Try to wrap the java command in a function like `chromhmm()`. Next test both `chromhmmm` and `chromhmmm 2>/dev/null`, I would expect that they both make the same count of output files.